Transformations in one query based on list of column names and required transformation - in another table
I want to make changes to some of the columns in my query MAIN.
Here is some sample data (all columns are numerical):
ID  | col1  | col2 | cola  | colb
1   |  1    |  17  |   3   |  10
2   |  3    |  6   |   5   |   5

Another query called CHANGES has a list of the required changes (all text columns):
varnm | cndvr| cndvl 
 col1 | col2 | 16,17,18,19   
 cola | colb | 5  

The change I am trying to do - for every row in table CHANGES:
find the columns named in varnm and cndvr - for every row check if the value in the cndvr column exists among the list of values in cndvl, the value in the varnm column remains unchaged. If, on the other hand, the value in the cndvr column does NOT exists among the list of values in cndvl, the value in the varnm column is changed to 9999.
So the expected result in MAIN look like this:
ID  | col1  | col2 | cola  | colb
1   |  1    |  17  | 9999  |  10
2   | 9999  |  6   |   5   |   5

I tried to do it by creating a function called REPFUNC:
(row as record, dt as table) as table =>
    let

        // Extract condition values
        varnm = Record.Field(row, "varnm"), // Column to transform
        cndvr = Record.Field(row, "cndvr"), // Column for condition
        cndvl = Text.Split(Record.Field(row, "cndvl"), ","),
    
        // Transform data based on the condition
        TransformedData = Table.ReplaceValue(
                    dt,
                    each varnm, 
                    each if List.Contains(cndvl, Text.From(cndvr)) then varnm else 999999, 
                    Replacer.ReplaceValue, 
                    {varnm}
                )
    in
        TransformedData

I call the function in my MAIN query like this:
let
    Source = ......,
    // Process each row in CHANGES
    ProcessedData = List.Accumulate(
        Table.ToRecords(CHANGES),
        Source,
        (state, currentRow) => Function.Invoke(REPFUNC, {currentRow, state})
    )
in
    ProcessedData

The result: NOTHING CHANGES.
ADDITIONALLY:
There is a great suggestion by @AlexisOlson in a similar problem here to simplify things by restructuring. I would unpivot the columns in varnm, merge CHANGES to MAIN, create a simple transformation step and pivot back.
The thing is some transformation in the original problem are stepped - so the same column may appear, more than once, in both varnm AND in cndvr - which seems to kill the unpivot option.
EDIT - adding code to recreate the example:
the MAIN data:
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        {{1, 1, 17, 3, 10},{2, 3, 6, 5, 5}},
        {"ID", "col1", "col2", "cola", "colb"})
in
    Source

The CHANGES table:
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        {{"col1", "col2", "16,17,18,19"},{"cola", "colb", "5"}},
        {"varnm", "cndvr", "cndvl"})
in
    Source


Here's one way, using the Table.TransformRows function with a Record.TransformFields argument:
REPFUNC
(r as record) => 

List.Accumulate(
    Table.ToRecords(CHANGES),
        r,
        (s,c)=> Record.TransformFields(s, {c[varnm], each 
        if List.Contains(Text.Split(c[cndvl],","), 
            Text.From(Record.Field(r,c[cndvr])) )  
        then _ 
        else 9999}))

MAIN
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
                {[ID=1,col1=1,col2=17,cola=3,colb=10],
                 [ID=2, col1=3,col2=6,cola=5,colb=5]},
                type table[ID=Int64.Type,col1=Int64.Type,col2=Int64.Type,cola=Int64.Type,colb=Int64.Type]),
    
    Transforms = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(Source, each REPFUNC(_))),
    
    Types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Transforms, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Transforms), each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    Types

CHANGES
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [varnm="col1",cndvr="col2",cndvl="16,17,18,19"],
        [varnm="cola", cndvr="colb",cndvl="5"]},
        type table[varnm=text, cndvr=text,cndvl=text])
in
    Source

Source

CHANGES

Results

Edit to show issue with your approach:
Your approach fails because in the Table.Replace function within REPFUNC your 2nd and 3rd arguments are not referring to the table in the first argument.To use that function within your original code, try:
(row as record, dt as table) as table =>
    let

        // Extract condition values
        varnm = Record.Field(row, "varnm"), // Column to transform
        cndvr = Record.Field(row, "cndvr"), // Column for condition
        cndvl = Text.Split(Record.Field(row, "cndvl"), ","),
    
        // Transform data based on the condition
        TransformedData = Table.ReplaceValue(
                    dt,
                    each Record.Field(_,cndvr),
                    "999999", 
                    (x,y,z) => if List.Contains(cndvl, Text.From(y)) then x else z,
                    {varnm}
                )
    in
        TransformedData


First, this works beautifully, THANKS! Secondly, I will study how your approach manages this, but would also be greatful if you can supply any insight on where my approach was failing so I can improve...

@eli-k Your approach fails because in the Table.Replace function within REPFUNC your 2nd and 3rd arguments are not referring to the table in the first argument. If you want to use that method (which by testing is slightly slower), I'll add a corrected version to my answer.

Than you so much, again! I got both a solution and a lesson.
